# How to use directive in more than one module in angular?

Tags: angular, module, directive

- created one directive uppercase-input.directive.ts
- and trying to import/use it in more than one components, but getting below error
- just posted here one file (organization.module.ts), there are few more where i used uppercase directive

*Error: src/app/core/directives/uppercase-input.directive.ts:8:14 - error NG6007: The Directive 'UppercaseInputDirective' is declared by more than one NgModule.
8 export class UppercaseInputDirective {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
× Failed to compile.*

**Here is my code :.**

*uppercase-input.directive.ts*

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[uppercase]',
  host: {
    '(input)': '$event'
  }
})
export class UppercaseInputDirective {

  lastValue!: string;

  constructor(public ref: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInput($event:any) 
  {
    var start = $event.target.selectionStart;
    var end = $event.target.selectionEnd;
    $event.target.value = $event.target.value.toUpperCase();
    $event.target.setSelectionRange(start, end);
    $event.preventDefault();

    if (!this.lastValue || (this.lastValue && $event.target.value.length > 0 && this.lastValue !== $event.target.value)) {
      this.lastValue = this.ref.nativeElement.value = $event.target.value;
      // Propagation
      const evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
      evt.initEvent('input', false, true);
      event?.target?.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
  }
}
```

*organization.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { OrganizationRegisterRoutingModule } from './organization-register-routing.module';
import { OrganizationRegisterComponent } from './organization-register.component';
import { AddOrganizationComponent } from './add-organization/add-organization.component';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
import { GlobalTableComponent } from 'src/app/shared/global-table/global-table.component';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UppercaseInputDirective } from 'src/app/core/directives/uppercase-input.directive';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    OrganizationRegisterComponent,
    AddOrganizationComponent,
    UppercaseInputDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CommonModule,
    OrganizationRegisterRoutingModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    GlobalTableComponent,
    MatTooltipModule
  ]
})
export class OrganizationRegisterModule { }
```

*app.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { NgxSpinnerModule } from 'ngx-spinner';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
// import { UnitRegistrationComponent } from './modules/procurement/masters/unit-registration/unit-registration.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    // UnitRegistrationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    NgxSpinnerModule,
    MatDialogModule
  ],
  providers: [DatePipe],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't exporting this directive solve the problem?

Try adding:

```
exports: [UppercaseInputDirective]
```

into your organization module decorator

Answer (score 0):

You're not suppose to import the the directive directly into the component that's using it. Instead, first create a module for the directive and import the directive into the module, like this:

```js
import {
  CommonModule
} from '@angular/common';
import {
  NgModule
} from '@angular/core';

import {
  UppercaseInputDirective 
} from './uppercase-input.directive.ts';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [UppercaseInputDirective],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [UppercaseInputDirective],
})
export class UppercaseInputDirectiveModule {}
```

Then, import your directive's module into the module of the component where you wish to use the directive, like this:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
// additional imports, including your component

import { UppercaseInputDirective } from '/path-to-your-directive-module'


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    OrganizationRegisterComponent,
    AddOrganizationComponent,
    // do NOT add the directive or module as a declaration here
  ],
  imports: [
    // ... other imports
    UppercaseInputDirective
  ]
})
export class OrganizationRegisterModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add it under `declarations` in `AppModule`.
If the directive is of a service type, add it under `providers` as well.
This should make it work.

The flow here is:
Your module/ component is registered in appModule.
Your directive is also registered in appModule.
With appModule as the common point, other components can get reference to the directive.